# splitting the world map into grids with h3

Tags: javascript, node.js, h3

```js
    <script>
        mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiYWhtZXRiYXlyYWtjaSIsImEiOiJja3lqN2lzemwxcDZnMzBxcDZ3OHVrdjU5In0.jgPDOZKWtnkHlZiinlNK6Q';
        const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: 'map',
            style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9',
            center: [-103.5917, 40.6699],
            zoom: 3
        });

        map.on('load', () => {
 
            map.addSource('earthquakes', {
                type: 'geojson',
 
                data: 'https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/earthquakes.geojson',
                cluster: true,
                clusterMaxZoom: 14,  
                clusterRadius: 50  
            });

map.addSource('urban-areas', {
'type': 'geojson',
'data': 'https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/ne_50m_urban_areas.geojson',
});
            map.addLayer({
                id: 'clusters',
                type: 'circle',
                source: 'earthquakes',
                filter: ['has', 'point_count'],
                paint: {
 
                    'circle-color': [
                        'step',
                        ['get', 'point_count'],
                        '#51bbd6',
                        100,
                        '#f1f075',
                        750,
                        '#f28cb1'
                    ],
                    'circle-radius': [
                        'step',
                        ['get', 'point_count'],
                        20,
                        100,
                        30,
                        750,
                        40
                    ]
                }
            });

            map.addLayer({
                id: 'cluster-count',
                type: 'symbol',
                source: 'earthquakes',
                filter: ['has', 'point_count'],
                layout: {
                    'text-field': '{point_count_abbreviated}',
                    'text-font': ['DIN Offc Pro Medium', 'Arial Unicode MS Bold'],
                    'text-size': 14
                }
            });

            map.addLayer({
                id: 'unclustered-point',
                type: 'circle',
                source: 'earthquakes',
                filter: ['!', ['has', 'point_count']],
                paint: {
                    'circle-color': '#ccc',
                    'circle-radius': 10,
                    'circle-stroke-width': 1,
                    'circle-stroke-color': '#fff'
                }
            });
            map.addLayer(
{
'id': 'urban-areas-fill',
'type': 'fill',
'source': 'urban-areas',
'layout': {},
'paint': {
'fill-color': '#f08',
'fill-opacity': 0.4
}
 
} 
);

 
            map.on('click', 'clusters', (e) => {
                const features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, {
                    layers: ['clusters']
                });
                const clusterId = features[0].properties.cluster_id;
                map.getSource('earthquakes').getClusterExpansionZoom(
                    clusterId,
                    (err, zoom) => {
                        if (err) return;

                        map.easeTo({
                            center: features[0].geometry.coordinates,
                            zoom: zoom
                        });
                    }
                );
            });
 
            map.on('click', 'unclustered-point', (e) => {
                const coordinates = e.features[0].geometry.coordinates.slice();
                const mag = e.features[0].properties.mag;
                const tsunami = e.features[0].properties.tsunami === 1 ? 'yes' : 'no';

 
                while (Math.abs(e.lngLat.lng - coordinates[0]) > 180) {
                    coordinates[0] += e.lngLat.lng > coordinates[0] ? 360 : -360;
                }
                new mapboxgl.Popup()
                    .setLngLat(coordinates)
                    .setHTML(
                        `magnitude: ${mag}<br>Was there a tsunami?: ${tsunami}`
                    )
                    .addTo(map);
            });
            map.on('mouseenter', 'clusters', () => {
                map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';
            });
            map.on('mouseleave', 'clusters', () => {
                map.getCanvas().style.cursor = '';
            });
            map.on("click", function (e) {
  // Convert a lat/lng point to a hexagon index at resolution 10
  const h3Index = h3.geoToH3(e.lngLat.lng, e.lngLat.lat, 10);
  // Get the center of the hexagon
  const hexCenterCoordinates = h3.h3ToGeo(h3Index);
  // Get the vertices of the hexagon
  const hexBoundary = h3.h3ToGeoBoundary(h3Index);
  hexBoundary.push(hexBoundary[0]); 
});
 
    });
        
    </script>
```

I found node.js examples for what I'm trying to do, but I don't know node.js. I need to run what is done here in html with js.

I want to create a new point to h3index code in map.on click.
how can i make these dots to be hexagon instead of round?

I've been trying for a long time and I couldn't.
example : https://www.marketplace.ovr.ai

Comment: I'm not clear on your question, or what you're trying to do. The Observable examples are all in client-side JS, not Node, though h3-js will run on either platform. Can you articulate the problem you're trying to solve and what barriers you're hitting?

Comment: I updated the question for you, can you take a look again?

Comment: I’m afraid I’m still a little confused about what you’re asking. Can you narrow your code down to just the part that shows the issue? Are you trying to make it show the H3 index boundary on click, and that’s not working?